# Edimax N300 factory reset not working (anymore)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wireless-extender

My WiFi extender including its resetting has worked well for years. But suddenly the orange router signal indicator stops blinking from times to times. So I try to go into the setup via the extender's default IP address 192.168.2.2
According to the manual: I switch it on, then instantly keep pressing the WPS button for minimum 15 seconds. But what happens now: The orange LED (router's signal strength) shines without blinking, and the power LED including all the others stays off.

Here are the words from the original manual:

> If your Wi-Fi extender is not functioning correctly, press and hold the WPS button for 10 seconds to reset the extender to factory defaults. The Power LED will flash when the device begins the process of resetting to factory defaults. When the Power LED stays on and the Wi-Fi LED begins flashing irregularly, the Wi-Fi extender has returned to factory default settings and is ready for setup.

And here is the IP of it, to go into the setup  http://192.168.2.2/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same extender, in another package (sitecom wlx-2003 v1) and was not able to perform a factory reset.

Same symptoms: 
upon turning on, power led for an instant
then steady signal strength (for 'very good connection')
no reaction on pressing the WPS/OPS button

What I did:

1. Open up the lid.
2. There's one screw under the sticker on the
   backside;
3. unscrew and take the lid of.
4. Press the tiny button for 15 seconds.
5. Wait for reset
6. Mine was accessible at 192.168.128.253, might differ depending on firmware

My guess: the springy bit of plastic under the WPS/OPS button got lame, and kept the micro switch pressed all the time.

My unit actually showed regular behaviour immediately after taking the lid off and plugging it in. Not the steady 'Signal very good' led, but blinking blue for WIFI and white on pressing the WPS/OPS.

I realize your question is from a while back, but what is half a year for a 5 year old unit :-)

Comment: Great idea! I will tell how mine behaved, after I've tried your easy method.